# Parametirized StringBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic gridview which can be used to add new rows of two columns to specify a start date and an end date. I am trying to use a string collection to pass in the output from the textboxes to a parameterized query as shows. I am getting an incorrect syntax near 9 error. How can I make this work? I need to use the stringbuilder. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
protected void btnSaveIterations_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    int rowIndex = 0;

    StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];


        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                //extract the TextBox values
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("start_iteration");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("end_iteration");

                start_date = box1.Text;
                end_date = box2.Text;

                //get the values from the TextBoxes
                //then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values

                sc.Add(proj_id + "," + start_date + "," + end_date);

                rowIndex++;

            }

            //Call the method for executing inserts

            InsertRecords(sc);
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());

            //r.Close();
            //conn.Close();

        }
    }
}

private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

    string[] splitItems = null;

    foreach (string item in sc)
    {
        const string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Iterations (ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (@ProjectID, @StartDate, @EndDate)";

        if (item.Contains(","))
        {

            splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2]);

        }
    }

    try
    {

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");

        cmd.Parameters["@ProjectID"].Value = proj_id;
        cmd.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(start_date, ci);
        cmd.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(end_date, ci);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ...
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Where exactly does the error occur

Answer (score 2):

You seem to mix up two different things:

With the StringBuilder you set the SQL text to a string containing the parameter placeholders, followed by another string containing the values:

> INSERT INTO Iterations (ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES(@ProjectID, ...)(12345, '2011-02-22', ...);

And later you set the parameters, but then you forget the single quotes around the dates - hence the 'incorrect syntax near 9' error.

Either you omit the whole SQL parameter stuff at the end and just set the values in your StringBuilder, giving

> INSERT INTO Iterations (ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (12345, '2011-02-22', ...);

or you omit the StringBuilder part and add the single quotes to your sqlStatement around the parameter placeholders:

> INSERT INTO Iterations (ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES(@ProjectID, '@StartDate', '@EndDate');

Answer (score 1):

You are using text from `sb` that is obviously incorrect sql. Correct code would be something like

```
...
const string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Iterations (ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (@ProjectID, @StartDate, @EndDate)";
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);

System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");

foreach (string item in sc)
{

    if (item.Contains(","))
    {
        splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());

        cmd.Parameters["@ProjectID"].Value = splitItems[0];
        cmd.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(splitItems[1], ci);
        cmd.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(splitItems[2], ci);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
...
```